# Memory leaks in C++ using FindFile and file handles

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, c++11, memory-leaks

I am writing an app that is moving files on windows and I have some memory leaks. I don't have access to the code now, but I know I forgot to close file handles used to iterate over files with FindFirstFile and FindNextFile. Can this cause memory leaks, or does something else have to be wrong with my code? I cannot post any fragments now, but I am wondering, if this me cause the problem.

Comment: *I don't have access to the code now* and *I cannot post any fragments now* - then wait to post until you have the access and can include code. *Why does my code not work properly?* without the code is just guessing, and this is not a *question and guess* or *question and speculation* site.

Comment: "*I know I forgot to close file handles used to iterate over files with FindFirstFile and FindNextFile*" - then you definitely have a leak, so why ask about it if you already know about it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is exactly what I want to know, if unclosed file handles might cause the memory leaks. I cannot post the code, cause it is on the computer in my office and I don't have access to it during the weekend. It just kept bothering me what might be wrong with the code, so I wanted to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Memory leaks are just a special case of resource leaks. File handles are resources, too. So you definitely leak resources of various kinds.

BTW, how do you check for memory leaks?

Your problem is not writing C++ code, but C code that's then compiled using a C++ compiler. WINAPI is not C++. To realistically use it from C++, you must wrap all resources in classes that implement RAII so that they can be safely used from your C++ code without worries about resource leaks. You should also be using the smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) to manage your memory.

Comment: I just checked how much memory the program is using and it is using much more than 2gigs, that is all for memory leaks checking. I am using some char* to arrays created with new char[] but I am using delete[] on those. I am not using any smart pointers, I don't know those.

Comment: @Fulaphex You *really* need to learn C++. So far, you're using C with `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`. The names are different, but you're still forcing yourself to manage memory manually. Most general purpose modern C++ code should read like, say, Python, with no explicit memory management of any kind. Make sure you're at least on most up to date Windows 7, the memory use indications on Windows XP were almost nonsensical.